# What is the maximum number of Sudoku boards possible?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, permutations, sudoku

Sudoku is a $9 \times 9$ board game subjected to $4$ conditions:

1. Only digits ($1-9$) can be used to fill a blank box.
2. All horizontal rows to be filled with digits without repeating a digit in row.
3. All vertical columns to be filled with digits without repeating a digit in a column.
4. All $3\times 3$ boxes to be filled with digits without repeating a digit in a box.

Let assume the other condition: every Sudoku board has a unique solution.
There is no restriction on the number of filled spaces and blank spaces.

Subject to these conditions, how many permutations of Sudoku boards are possible?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku#Enumerating_Sudoku_solutions

Comment: See also [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023071/number-of-possible-sudoku-puzzles) (which has mostly the same wikipedia source + sparse material).

Comment: You should edit to $(1-9)$, you can't fill a sudoku with a 0

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan thanks, made the edit